# Rounds in python game

Tags: python

Brand new to programming any tips on how to add rounds into this random name game in python?

```
from random import randint

score = 0

print("To play please enter your names")

num_players = input ('Enter number of players: ')

name = input('type your name: ')

name2 = input('type your name: ')

name3 = input('type your name: ')

name4 = input('type your  name: ')

name5 = input('type your name: ')

print('NAMES OF PLAYERS WILL APPEAR HERE:')

print(name, name2, name3, name4, name5)

names = {1: name, 2: name2, 3: name3, 4: name4, 5:name5,}

print('WINNER:')

x = randint(1,5)

print(names[x])

score = score +1

print("Score is : " ,score)

input('Press ENTER to exit ')
```

Answer (score 2):

You should wrap the main functionality in a loop.

```
from random import randint

print("To play please enter your names")
keep_playing = 'y'

while keep_playing == 'y'
    score = 0

    num_players = input ('Enter number of players: ')

    name = input('type your name: ')

    name2 = input('type your name: ')

    name3 = input('type your name: ')

    name4 = input('type your  name: ')

    name5 = input('type your name: ')

    print('NAMES OF PLAYERS WILL APPEAR HERE:')

    print(name, name2, name3, name4, name5)

    names = {1: name, 2: name2, 3: name3, 4: name4, 5:name5,}

    print('WINNER:')

    x = randint(1,5)

    print(names[x])

    score = score +1

    print("Score is : " ,score)

    keep_playing = input('Would you like to keep playing[y/n]').lower()
```